# Create Apk from angular 4 project

Tags: angular, admin, angular2-template

I wanted to create one application for administrator of society committee. I have used ngx-admin template created by aveko, but i don't know how to create apk of my admin application. I wanted to show how it will work on my real device after require modification. Does anyone know?

Comment: You can use Ionic : https://ionicframework.com/

Comment: yes i can but my application requirement is ngx-admin

Comment: And ? That doesn't mean you can't use ngx-admin.

Comment: sorry but i really dont know how to create apk of ngx-admin based project.Are you telling me to use ionic cli ?As i know ngx-admin is baked on angular4 and angualar is not ionic project so i think i am not able to use ionic cli on angular project. and if i can use it then let me know how it will work.

Comment: I'll make you an answer then, wait a while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use Angular, you create **Single Page Applications**, known as SPA.

This means that, opposed to languages such as PHP, **you user doesn't request for a page to your server**. In Angular, **all of your pages are held by the user's computer**.

When creating SPA, you are using **JavaScript**. Javascript has **nothing to do with Java**. This means, if you want to create an APK, **you will need to create a Java project**.

But fortunately for you, there is a framework called **Ionic**. This framework allows you to create APKs for your SPA applications.

From what I have understood, it creates an application made of only a web browser, that will display your SPA. This tricks the user into thinking he uses a native application, but in fact, **he uses a SPA**.

To acces the phone's properties, Ionic relies on another Framework, named **Cordova**. This framework give you an abstraction that allow you to access things such as contacts, pictures and such.

Applied to your issue : **you can use Ionic and Cordova, regardless of ngx-admin**. Because in the end, you will **build your application**, thus making **vendor scripts**. Those scripts will contain **every piece of Javascript your application uses**, and that includes ngx-admin.

Once you've built your application, Ionic will **serve this SPA in a browser** on your user's phone.

So, all you have to do now, is use Ionic ! And another plus side : **Ionic can also create iPhone applications**.

A little pice of advice : from what I've understood, you want to show your client what your application will look like on a phone, right ? In this case, you can deplloy your SPA on a server like a standard application, and reach for it with your phone. This will allow you to gain so much time that you will actually have time to discover Ionic on your own !

Comment: so are you telling me to create ionic app and integrate ngx-admin template which is based on angular ? is it possible ? i dont think so

Comment: I'm telling you to use Ionic. How you do that is up to you. But to answer you, yes, it's possible. If you have read anything I've written, you will understand why.

Comment: hey can u give me any link or example how to integrate ngx-admin template into ionic app. it will really help me as i have already created ionic app.but i have tried to integrate it but i got so many errors and i am not abl to resolve it,So if u have any example,link,tutorial it will be very heplfull for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: No I've got none. You have to correct your errors (or ask on SOF for help) one at a time. But just let me say : if you have followed the brest practice when coding with Angular, then you should have no issue integrating your application into an Ionic one :)

Comment: what if i am new for the technologyso how can i follow the best practice while coding with angular

Comment: Like every new developper, you [follow the style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) !

Comment: No problem ! remember one thing : Angular is maintained by Google. Their docs are thorough and exhaustive. if you have any question or doubt, be sure to first take a look at their website, they probably have your solution !

Comment: okay thanks for the valuable advise,i'll surely follow it. and i am very sorry for my poor english

Comment: Don't apologize, your english is very good : you can be understood easily ! And trust me, on stack overflow, that's a rare asset ;)

Comment: There is also other ways to build apk . Like PWA approach.